# Ignoring properties and accessors while using jackson

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson, jax-rs

I have a POJO which i need to serialize into JSON. The POJO has a lot of properties and I would like to serialize only a few of them into the JSON representation. I am using jackson to serialize. Since there are a lot of properties that i want to ignore it looks very ugly to annotate each of them as @JsonIgnore

Do is there a way to tell jackson or configure objectMapper to only include properties when its annotated as @JsonProperty and ignore the rest without specifying @JsonIgnore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set your object mapper like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setVisibilityChecker(mapper.getDeserializationConfig().getDefaultVisibilityChecker()
        .withCreatorVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
        .withFieldVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
        .withGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
        .withIsGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
        .withSetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE));
```

Credits to [Horte](https://gist.github.com/horte/1960310) :)

Answer (score 2):

By extension to Enrichman's answer, you could also annotate your POJO class to achieve the same effect:

```
@JsonAutoDetect(
    creatorVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE, 
    fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE,
    getterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE,
    isGetterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE,
    setterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE
)
public class MyPojo {

    // fields, getters, setter, constructors, etc.

}
```

This would ignore everything in your POJO not annotated with `JsonProperty` by default.

Answer (score 0):

```
@JsonAutoDetect(JsonMethod.NONE)
```

Will ignore all field in class that not annotated by `@JsonProperty`

But its only for org.codehaus.jackson not com.fasterxml.jackson